# Racoons: What sort of protection do my rabbit enclosure need?

Tags: rabbits, containment, outdoor

I have two dwarf rabbits in an enclosure in the backyard.

Some time ago I heared about some rabbits catched by a group of racoons. (In a place some away. Here I havend heared about or seen racoons.)

What protection do my rabbits need? (They will not come indoors.)

Especially I need information about the power of racoons: How smart and how strong are they? And what material can resist them?

(Today my rabbits have an enclosure with this protection: [What boundaries are necessary for outdoor rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/what-boundaries-are-necessary-for-outdoor-rabbits) )

Comment: Raccoons are both very smart and very strong. I think you will need a wire-mesh enclosure that is completely closed.

Comment: My rabbits have a wire mesh enclosure with point welded wire, so it can not be ripped of. The mesh is attached on wooden frames. They are bound together with screws. The door and the roof/cap are bound with hinge and lock bolt. The wooden frames stand on flagging, bound through their own weight. So the enclosure is completely closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I can not find any source how one can prevent that raccoons enter the rabbit enclosure, I turned my point of view:

**What let pet raccoons stay in their own enclosure?**

(If they can not get out, they would not get in is my thinking)

To this Question there are a lots of sources, I will give a resume:

1. The grid should be stable, for example "10x10 dog kennel chain link fence" [1] or "Wire should be 1"X2" welded wire" [2]
2. Doors should be difficult to open, i.e. "Raccoons have almost human-like hands where they can open cupboards and refrigerators" [1]
3. They can scratch trough wooden board: "If they want in bad enough, they will scratch the door and carpet. If you are concerned about your doors, you can put some kick plates on the bottom of the door. This will prevent the raccoon from scratching any holes in the door." [1]

**What I will change at my rabbit enclosure:**

In my Question I linked how my enclosure today is build.

I will add:

1. padlocks at the stable doors, until today there are wooden lock bars (wooden bar screwed at the frame). Same thing at the hutch roof (able to open to clean inside).
2. I use proper wire yet, but I can improve the binding of it to the wooden frames. As I build it I bond the wire with a little stapler to the wood, but now I think I should screw it or at least nail it together.
3. I want to anchoring the enclosure better on the ground, so it can not be lifted. I have no estimation how much power raccoons have, so I have to assume, they may do it.
4. I will check the wood daily for scratches. New wood will be thick or covered with some "scratch protection" like the mentioned metal plate.

Sources:

[1] [Care Sheet For Racoons](https://sybilsden.com/caresheet/raccoons.htm)

[2] [raccoonworld.com](https://www.raccoonworld.com/raccoonrehab.html#4)

Answer (score 1):

Raccoons are very smart, resourceful and strong as well as determined, the more challenging the venture the more resourceful they will be. Most wild raccoons as well as coyotes are shy of lights though, a motion sensitivity light or and sound will keep predators at bay. It might put your mind at ease to walk the perimeter of your yard, especially the pets areas with human scent, and though this will appear odd to passers by, cougar or coyote urine, and human cologne or perfume dentures wild animals but not domestic dogs and cats and such. Switch scents off now and again, you can drag a cloth doused or put it on your shoes and gloves before or as you walk your area.

With the scent on your gloves touch spots that look like an animal might pause and look at or hide, like trees, fence post, flower or garden beds, the gates and doors windows, lawn decor furniture etc. Don't leave food out at night, try to feed your pets during the day. Don't leave the dishes out over night.

Comment: The scent thing is a good idea. We use the garden where my rabbits live regularly. I have to walk it once a day to search for "escape tunnels" built by our rabbits. But the food part is difficult. Do racoons be affected to vegetables? On day our rabbits eat the garden, on night they need food inside their enclosure.