# Temporary, safe, outside cage for degus?

Tags: cage, rodents

We have 3 degus at home.

They seem to be happy with their cage, and are allowed to roam free once a day in a closed room, in which every plastic stuff has been removed.

I'd like to find a way for our degus to safely enjoy direct sun, fresh air and fresh grass.

As any other degu, they're very curious and are escape artists. There should be absolutely no way for them to escape to other parts of the building. There should also be no way for birds of prey to attack our degus.

Do you know of any reliable technique to do so?

We have a roof terrace, I was thinking of this procedure:

- buy a middle-size, metallic bird cage.
- add a water bottle.
- add a wooden house for them to hide if necessary.
- add a wooden plank to the upper part of the cage, so that at least part of the cage is always shadowed.
- In the closed room, lure the degus into the bird cage, with food or a cardboard tunnel.
- Close the bird cage once all 3 degus are inside.
- Bring the cage outside, and leave it on grass, so that the degus can eat flowers through the cage, but not dig.
- Leave them outside, supervised, and let them sunbath if they want.
- Bring them back, close the room, open the cage.

Did you ever try something similar? Do you have any better idea?

Comment: a rabbit cage made with metall mesh is probably the best option for your pet`s needs https://www.thesprucepets.com/degus-as-pets-1236773

Comment: @trondhansen: Thanks. I thought about it too. The cages I found in the neighborhood had a mesh which was definitely too wide for degus.

Comment: If you have fox, marten and smaller predators, you should also pretend them from getting inside. You can have a look for questions about rabbit outdoor enclosure here, there I have explained how to do so for rabbits. https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/what-boundaries-are-necessary-for-outdoor-rabbits

Comment: @Allerleirauh: Ground predators shouldn't be able to reach our terrace. The biggest danger would probably be falcons and crows.

Comment: Marten are very well climbers! Sometimes better than cats... Racoons are also very smart... You need to decide, depending of your area :)

Comment: @Allerleirauh I didn't know that. Still, we live on the 4th floor and we'll never leave the degus outside unattended. I really don't think martens or foxes would be a problem on our terrace. And if the cage is built so that degus cannot get out, I don't think larger predators could harm them.

Comment: As example: A pine marten climbs a brick wall in this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=C3kIbt271R0 or this one https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KjHHSQiz5DA